# Keras running in Docker very slow and crashes - ValueError: Feature my_feature is not in features dictionary

Tags: docker, tensorflow, keras

I can run Keras neural net locally on my W10 laptop fine

But same code running in Docker is extremely slow and always crashes with error:

```
ValueError: Feature my_feature is not in features dictionary.
```

The feature *not found* is always the target feature

There are version differences between laptop and container but I'm not convinced this has bearing

Laptop

```
Windows 10 Enterprise 64bit
Intel Core i7-7820HQ @ 2.90GHz
16GB RAM

Python 3.6.5 (v3.6.5:f59c0932b4, Mar 28 2018, 17:00:18) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

λ pip list | grep tensorflow
tensorflow               2.0.0
tensorflow-estimator     2.0.1

λ pip list | grep pandas
pandas                   0.23.3
pandas-ml                0.6.1

λ pip list | grep numpy
numpy                    1.17.4
```

Docker

```
# cat /etc/os-release      
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)"    
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"                       
VERSION_ID="9"                                
VERSION="9 (stretch)"                         
VERSION_CODENAME=stretch                      
ID=debian                                     
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"            
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"  
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/" 

Python 3.6.10 (default, Apr 23 2020, 15:40:23)
[GCC 6.3.0 20170516] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

root@modelbuilder:~# pip list | grep tensorflow
tensorflow             2.3.0
tensorflow-estimator   2.3.0

root@modelbuilder:~# pip list | grep pandas
pandas                 0.24.0
pandas-ml              0.6.1

root@modelbuilder:~# pip list | grep numpy
numpy                  1.19.2
```

Verified what was mentioned here: [ValueError: Feature not in features dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47635507/valueerror-feature-not-in-features-dictionary)

Target is not being fed into feature columns, features correspond etc, and this would also fail locally.

Any help will be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out.

Crash issue:
In error created feature column for target, so removed the target from features for columns

Slow Docker:
Was running `model.fit()` over and over (many times)